# iOS hide time on status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to hide just the **time** on the status bar in iOS programatically? I'm aware of the code to hide/show entire status bar, but I would like to keep everything on status bar except the time.

```
// Code to hide status bar completely; but that's not what I want
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After some thinking, I just placed an image with the same color of the topbar and performed hide/unhide whenever time was to be removed. Not a very elegant solution but serves the purpose

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no way you can hide the time but keep all other status bar items. Either you hide the whole status bar, or you keep it whole.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY want to hide the time, you still can hide all the StatusBar and create your own one without the time ;)

Comment: That is very brave thing to do, but I believe it is doable. You should show more than just an "idea" but even for that +1! :)

Comment: Good luck! There are literally dozens of edge cases you're probably not even aware they exist. TTY icon, anyone?

Comment: Not something even experienced developers would have a go at. I wouldn't recommend it at all.

Comment: I can't show more because I never did it. But I think I'll try. It can be fun to have a custom status bar.

Comment: After some thinking, I just placed an image with the same color of the topbar and performed hide/unhide whenever time was to be removed.  Not a very elegant solution but serves the purpose.